# SignalR 1.1 Beta1 and server certificate

Tags: signalr

I am using SignalR 1.1 beta. My Controller code is as below

```
_signalUrl = "https://localhost/signalr";
_hubConnection = new HubConnection(_signalUrl);
_proxy = _hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");
_hubConnection.Start().Wait(); // throws error
```

Below are the error details

InnerException  {"The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."}    System.Exception {System.Net.WebException}

InnerException  {"The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure."}    System.Exception {System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException}

Stack Trace
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait().

When deployed to server with certificate, works fine using domain name (`https://domainname.com/signalr`). But not with IP Address (`https://IPAddress/signalr`).

Also tried adding client certificate by below code.

```
_proxy = _hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");
X509Certificate certificate = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("MyCert.cer");
_hubConnection.Start(new MyHttpClient() { Certificate = certificate }).Wait();
```

How to configure custom client certificate before starting the hub connection?

Any idea, Thanks in advance.

Praveen

Answer (score 0):

Add the cert to the collection.

```
_hubConnection = new HubConnection(_signalUrl);
_proxy = _hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");
_hubConnection.AddClientCertificate(X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("MyCert.cer"));
_hubConnection.Start().Wait();
```

Comment: Thanks David, I have downloaded the beta from nuget package using the below command PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -Pre The client.dll details are as below Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client(16757...)
File Version 1.1.20410.0
Product Version 1.1.0-beta1. Unable to see AddClientCertificate method